# Error: ‘log2’ is not a member of ‘std’

Tags: c++, namespaces, makefile, std

I am trying to compile a project using make command.
I have several occured errors about namespace std::.
I am using Ubuntu and I think I've installed all I need to compile C++ language.

Here's the code:

```
    #include "texture.hpp"
#include "texturefetch.hpp"

#include <png.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string>

Texture::~Texture(){
    delete[] mPixels;
    for (int i=1; i<mlodmax+1; ++i)
        delete[] mMipMapLevels[i];
    delete[] mMipMapLevels;
}

bool Texture::getclamp() const
{
    return clamp;
}

void Texture::setclamp(bool value)
{
    clamp = value;
}

int Texture::load(std::string filename){
    FILE *fp;
    png_byte magic[8];

    /* open image file */
    fp = std::fopen (filename.c_str(), "rb");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: couldn't open \"%s\"!\n", filename.c_str());
        return 0;
    }

    /* read magic number */
    fread (magic, 1, sizeof (magic), fp);

    /* check for valid magic number */
    if (!png_check_sig (magic, sizeof (magic))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: \"%s\" is not a valid PNG image!\n", filename.c_str());
        fclose (fp);
        return 0;
    }

    /* create a png read struct */
    png_structp png_ptr = png_create_read_struct (PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (!png_ptr) {
        fclose (fp);
        return 0;
    }

    /* create a png info struct */
    png_infop info_ptr = png_create_info_struct (png_ptr);
    if (!info_ptr) {
        fclose (fp);
        png_destroy_read_struct (&png_ptr, NULL, NULL);
        return 0;
    }

    /* initialize the setjmp for returning properly after a libpng
       error occured */
    if (setjmp (png_jmpbuf (png_ptr))) {
        fclose (fp);
        png_destroy_read_struct (&png_ptr, &info_ptr, NULL);
        return 0;
    }
    /* setup libpng for using standard C fread() function
       with our FILE pointer */
    png_init_io (png_ptr, fp);

    /* tell libpng that we have already read the magic number */
    png_set_sig_bytes (png_ptr, sizeof (magic));

    /* read png info */
    png_read_info (png_ptr, info_ptr);

    int bit_depth, color_type;

    /* get some usefull information from header */
    bit_depth = png_get_bit_depth (png_ptr, info_ptr);
    color_type = png_get_color_type (png_ptr, info_ptr);
    /* convert index color images to RGB images */
    if (color_type == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_PALETTE)
      png_set_palette_to_rgb (png_ptr);
    /* convert 1-2-4 bits grayscale images to 8 bits
       grayscale. */
    if (color_type == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY && bit_depth < 8)
      png_set_expand_gray_1_2_4_to_8(png_ptr);

    if (png_get_valid (png_ptr, info_ptr, PNG_INFO_tRNS))
      png_set_tRNS_to_alpha (png_ptr);
    if (bit_depth == 16)
      png_set_strip_16 (png_ptr);
    else if (bit_depth < 8)
      png_set_packing (png_ptr);
    /* update info structure to apply transformations */
    png_read_update_info (png_ptr, info_ptr);

    /* retrieve updated information */
    png_get_IHDR (png_ptr, info_ptr,
                  (png_uint_32*)(&mWidth),
                  (png_uint_32*)(&mHeight),
                  &bit_depth, &color_type,
                  NULL, NULL, NULL);
    switch (color_type) {
      case PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY:
        mPixelFormat = 1;
        break;

      case PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY_ALPHA:
        mPixelFormat = 2;
        break;

      case PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB:
        mPixelFormat = 3;
        break;

      case PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB_ALPHA:
        mPixelFormat = 4;
        break;

      default:
        /* Badness */
        break;
      }

    /* we can now allocate memory for storing pixel data */
    mPixels = new unsigned char[mWidth * mHeight * mPixelFormat];

    png_bytep *row_pointers;

    /* setup a pointer array.  Each one points at the begening of a row. */
    row_pointers = new png_bytep[mHeight];

    for (int i = 0; i < mHeight; ++i) {
        row_pointers[i] = (png_bytep)(mPixels +
          ((mHeight - (i + 1)) * mWidth * mPixelFormat));
    }

    /* read pixel data using row pointers */
    png_read_image (png_ptr, row_pointers);

    /* finish decompression and release memory */
    png_read_end (png_ptr, NULL);
    png_destroy_read_struct (&png_ptr, &info_ptr, NULL);

    fclose (fp);

    /* we don't need row pointers anymore */
    delete[] row_pointers;
    return 1;
}

Texture::Texture(std::string filename) : mPixels(NULL), mMipMapLevels(NULL), hasmipmap(false), mSu(1.f), mSv(1.f), clamp(false){
    if (!load(filename)) {
        std::cerr << "Erreur : impossible de lire le fichier " << filename << std::endl;
    } else {
        mlodmax = (int)std::floor(std::min(std::log2(mWidth), std::log2(mHeight)));
    }
}

bool Texture::prefilter(){
    hasmipmap = buildmipmaps();
    return hasmipmap;
}

bool Texture::buildmipmaps(){
    mMipMapLevels = new unsigned char*[mlodmax+1];
    mMipMapLevels[0] = mPixels;
    for (int i=1;i<mlodmax+1; ++i)
        mMipMapLevels[i]=NULL;

    // Call of the student function
    return prefilterTexture(mMipMapLevels, mWidth, mHeight, mPixelFormat, mlodmax+1);

}

void Texture::setScale(float su, float sv){
    mSu = 1.f/su;
    mSv = 1.f/sv;
}


void Texture::getPixel(float u, float v, float lod, Color &color){

        if (clamp){
            u = (u>0) ? ((u<1) ? u : 1) : 0;
            v = (v>0) ? ((v<1) ? v : 1) : 0;
        }

        u = mSu*u;
        v = mSv*v;

        float scaledU = u * (mWidth - 1);
        float scaledV = v * (mHeight - 1);
//        color = Color(u,v,0);
//        return;

        int s = ((int)scaledU) % mWidth;
        int t = ((int)scaledV) % mHeight;


        float ds = scaledU - std::floor(scaledU);
        float dt = scaledV - std::floor(scaledV);

        if (s<0){
            s = s+mWidth;
        }
        if (t<0){
            t = t+mHeight;
        }

        // Nearest
//        color = interpolate(mPixels, mWidth, mHeight, s,t, 0.f,0.f);
//        return;

         // Linear
//         color = interpolate(mPixels, mWidth, mHeight, s,t, ds, dt);
//         return;

        /* Filtrage */
        lod = std::min(lod-1, (float)mlodmax);
        if (lod > 0) {
//            color = Color(0, std::floor(lod), 0);
//            return;

            int baselod = (int)std::floor(lod);
            int pix = (int)(std::pow(2.f,baselod)); // bigger inferior mipmap level

            if (hasmipmap){
                // Sous-echantillonnage --> filtrage mip-map
                Color color1 = integrateMipMap(baselod, ((float)s + ds)/pix, ((float)t + dt)/pix, mWidth/pix, mHeight/pix);

                if (baselod < mlodmax){
                    pix = std::pow(2.f,baselod+1); // smaller superior mipmap level
                    Color color2 = integrateMipMap(baselod+1, ((float)s + ds)/pix, ((float)t + dt)/pix, mWidth/pix, mHeight/pix);

                    float dm = lod - std::floor(lod);
                    color = color1 * (1-dm) + color2 * dm;
                } else {
                    color = color1;
                }
            } else {
                int cs = pix * (s/pix);
                int ct = pix * (t/pix);
                Color color1 = integrateExplicit(mMipMapLevels[0], mWidth, mHeight, mPixelFormat, cs, ct, pix, pix);

                if (baselod < mlodmax){
                    pix = std::pow(2.f,baselod+1); // smaller superior mipmap level
                    cs = pix * (s/pix);
                    ct = pix * (t/pix);
                    Color color2 = integrateExplicit(mMipMapLevels[0], mWidth, mHeight, mPixelFormat, cs, ct, pix, pix);

                    float dm = lod - std::floor(lod);
                    color = color1 * (1-dm) + color2 * dm;
                } else {
                    color = color1;
                }

            }
        } else {
//            color = Color(1/*fabsf(lod)*/, 0, 0);
//            return;

            color = interpolate(mPixels, mWidth, mHeight, s,t, ds,dt);
        }

}

Color Texture::integrateMipMap(int level, float s, float t, int w, int h){
    Color color(0.f, 0.f, 0.f);
    color = interpolate(mMipMapLevels[level], w, h, (int)s, (int)t, s-std::floor(s), t-std::floor(t));
    return color;
}

Color Texture::integrateExplicit(unsigned char *pixels, int imageWidth, int imageHeight, int pixelFormat, float s, float t, int w, int h){

#if 0
    Color color(0.f, 0.f, 0.f);
    for (int i=0; i<h; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<w; j++) {
            int k = ((int)(t+i)) % imageHeight;
            int l = ((int)(s+j)) % imageWidth;
            int linPos = (k*imageWidth + l)*(pixelFormat);
            Color centerColor(((float) pixels[linPos])/255.0, ((float) pixels[linPos+1])/255.0, ((float) pixels[linPos+2])/255.0);
            color = color + centerColor;
        }
    color = color * (1.f/(w*h));
    return color;
#endif
    // Call of the student function
    return integrateTexture(pixels, imageWidth, imageHeight, pixelFormat, s, t, w, h);
}

Color Texture::interpolate(unsigned char *pixels, int w, int h, int s, int t, float ds, float dt){

#if 0
    Color color;
    // Sur échantillonnage --> interpolation
    // nearest texel
    int linPos = (t*w + s)*(mPixelFormat);
    Color centerColor(((float) pixels[linPos])/255.0, ((float) pixels[linPos+1])/255.0, ((float) pixels[linPos+2])/255.0);

    Color rightColor;
    int r = std::min(s+1, w-1);
    int posds = (t*w + r)*(mPixelFormat);
    rightColor = Color(
                      ((float) pixels[posds])/255.0,
                      ((float) pixels[posds+1])/255.0,
                      ((float) pixels[posds+2])/255.0
                  );
    Color upColor;
    int p = std::min(t+1, h-1);
    int posdt = (p*w + s)*(mPixelFormat);
    upColor = Color (
                    ((float) pixels[posdt])/255.0,
                    ((float) pixels[posdt+1])/255.0,
                    ((float) pixels[posdt+2])/255.0
              );
    Color upRightColor;
    int posdtds = (p*w + r)*(mPixelFormat);
    upRightColor = Color (
                         ((float) pixels[posdtds])/255.0,
                         ((float) pixels[posdtds+1])/255.0,
                         ((float) pixels[posdtds+2])/255.0
                   );
    rightColor = centerColor*(1-ds) + rightColor*ds;
    upColor = upColor*(1-ds) + upRightColor*ds;
    color = rightColor*(1-dt) + upColor*dt;
    return color;
#endif

    // Call of the student function
    return interpolateTexture(pixels, w, h, mPixelFormat, (float)s+ds, (float)t+dt);

}
```

And here's errors in terminal:

```
 In file included from /home/celine/OIM-LancerDeRayons-2014/coreraytracer/texture.cpp:1:0:
/home/celine/OIM-LancerDeRayons-2014/coreraytracer/texture.hpp: In member function ‘float Texture::computeMipmapLevel(const Vector3D&, const Vector3D&)’:
/home/celine/OIM-LancerDeRayons-2014/coreraytracer/texture.hpp:55:16: error: ‘log2’ is not a member of ‘std’
         return std::log2(std::max(dTdx.norm()*width()*mSu, dTdy.norm()*height()*mSv));
                ^
/home/celine/OIM-LancerDeRayons-2014/coreraytracer/texture.hpp:55:16: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:374:0,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/bits/os_defines.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/bits/c++config.h:426,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath:41,
                 from /home/celine/OIM-LancerDeRayons-2014/coreraytracer/vector3d.hpp:3,
                 from /home/celine/OIM-LancerDeRayons-2014/coreraytracer/texture.hpp:4,
                 from /home/celine/OIM-LancerDeRayons-2014/coreraytracer/texture.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/math-finite.h:344:15: note:   ‘log2’
 extern double __REDIRECT_NTH (log2, (double), __log2_finite);
               ^
/home/celine/OIM-LancerDeRayons-2014/coreraytracer/texture.cpp: In constructor ‘Texture::Texture(std::string)’:
/home/celine/OIM-LancerDeRayons-2014/coreraytracer/texture.cpp:162:44: error: ‘log2’ is not a member of ‘std’
         mlodmax = (int)std::floor(std::min(std::log2(mWidth), std::log2(mHeight)));
                                            ^
/home/celine/OIM-LancerDeRayons-2014/coreraytracer/texture.cpp:162:44: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:374:0,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/bits/os_defines.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/bits/c++config.h:426,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath:41,
                 from /home/celine/OIM-LancerDeRayons-2014/coreraytracer/vector3d.hpp:3,
                 from /home/celine/OIM-LancerDeRayons-2014/coreraytracer/texture.hpp:4,
                 from /home/celine/OIM-LancerDeRayons-2014/coreraytracer/texture.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/math-finite.h:344:15: note:   ‘log2’
 extern double __REDIRECT_NTH (log2, (double), __log2_finite);
               ^
/home/celine/OIM-LancerDeRayons-2014/coreraytracer/texture.cpp:162:63: error: ‘log2’ is not a member of ‘std’
         mlodmax = (int)std::floor(std::min(std::log2(mWidth), std::log2(mHeight)));
                                                               ^
/home/celine/OIM-LancerDeRayons-2014/coreraytracer/texture.cpp:162:63: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:374:0,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/bits/os_defines.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/bits/c++config.h:426,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/cmath:41,
                 from /home/celine/OIM-LancerDeRayons-2014/coreraytracer/vector3d.hpp:3,
                 from /home/celine/OIM-LancerDeRayons-2014/coreraytracer/texture.hpp:4,
                 from /home/celine/OIM-LancerDeRayons-2014/coreraytracer/texture.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/math-finite.h:344:15: note:   ‘log2’
 extern double __REDIRECT_NTH (log2, (double), __log2_finite);
```

I took a look on internet and I tried to include  and  but it's still not working...

Thanks!

Comment: Tip: for future questions, try to isolate the problem. Calling a specific function can be done in 4 lines of code. That would also have produced a much clearer error message.

Comment: What is the OS version and compiler version? Ubuntu is mainstream, and I would not expect it to have this problem in 2014 or 2016. Ubuntu 16 and 14 are OK. Are you using Ubuntu 12 or 10 with GCC 4.6 or 4.4? What is your command line? Does it include `-std=c++11`?

Answer (score 4):

`log2` is a C99 function. It's not in C++98, and therefore not in the `std` namespace. Either compile in C++11 mode (C++11 is aligned with C99):

```
// g++ -std=c++11
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::log2(3) << std::endl;
}
```

... or get the function from the C header, without the namespace:

```
// g++ -std=c++98
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << log2(3) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I do not use g++ command to compile, I used cmake then make.
Actually it is a project from my school and the first step it's to compile. I should not modify make files or anything else...

Comment: Then complain to your teacher, because his project is broken.

Comment: I will ;)
Keep in touch

Comment: In the CMake configuration file, the compiler and compiler options can be specified.